# Why Xamarin app not see using microsoft.net.http

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I need use httpclient

I install nuget package - Microsoft.Net.Http

after I see in reference - Microsoft.Net.Http

but when I try add using:

```
using Microsoft.Net.Http;
```

visual studio say, that have only Microsoft.Win32

I try restart vs and rebuild and nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class has a namespace. For `HttpClient` the namespace is `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. To use `HttpClient` in your application you need:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Very often the Classes inside the nuget package will have a namespace that starts with the nuget package name, but that is not a requirement. In this case its different.

Comment: Thanks!!! before I try add this reference vithout install nuget package, but in code not see httpclient

Answer (score 1):

Everything other than "System.*" needs to be reffered to somehow.

In this case its a nugget package.

[Click here for refference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)

Comment: thanks, but if need for Android and need httpclient?